# How to edit Items text in email template of magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am stuck with magento email template.

kindly refer the picture for understand my problem

thanks

[image: Magento email template problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this text in

```
 app->design->frontend->base->default->template->email->order->items->order->default.phtml
```

after the line number 103 you can get the order total calculation printing information which is display in new order email template.

Search for your label which you wanted to change.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the solution but the problem was somewhere else and i fixed by my own :)

Comment: Can you update the answer

Comment: actually i was using sstech abandoned cart module and the problem was in its emailreport file, i fixed it in the same way as you said :)

Comment: Please upvote and select as answer if this answer is useful, that other can use it